# Пунктуация при использовании паразитического выражения

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология

У одного из героев книги есть паразитическое выражение в речи: "Веришь, нет?"
Если ставить это выражение отдельным предложением, оно слишком мешает чтению. Гораздо удобнее читать, когда этот паразит отделён от основной фразы запятой.
Но паразит - вопросительное предложение! А необходимо передать интонацию основного предложения. Позволительно ли опустить вопросительный знак?
Например:
"- Ишь ты! Прыткий! Самого старого Свиндле обскакал, веришь, нет! – слова были вроде бы одобрительные, но в голосе Бендрагара одобрения не чувствовалось ни на грош. – Человек это стучит. Железом по железу, веришь, нет!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Веришь, нет" - **вводное сочетание со значением обращения к собеседнику**, при этом оно может иметь **разное графическое оформление в зависимости от структуры предложения:** 1) может разделяться запятой или тире; 2) может быть отдельным вопросительным предложением; 3) вопросительный знак ставится или в отдельном предложении, или на конце предложения, но не  середине. 4) перед вводным словом может стоять двоеточие.

― Ишь ты! Прыткий! Самого старого Свиндле обскакал, веришь, нет? ― Слова были вроде бы одобрительные, но в голосе Бендрагара одобрения не чувствовалось ни на грош.

― Человек это стучит. Железом по железу: веришь, нет?

**Примеры:**

Я же вижу по глазам: **не веришь, нет?**.. [И. Меттер. Сухарь (1979)]

**Веришь, нет:** ночью думаю-думаю ― до того плохо станет, хоть кричи. [Василий Шукшин. В профиль и анфас (1970)]

― **Веришь, нет,** а из всего детства только это и запомнил. [Виктор Мясников. Водка (2000)]

А у нас, брат, какие леса, **веришь ― нет**, медведей что мышей, в каждом малиннике двое-трое сидит. [Петр Алешковский. Жизнеописание Хорька (1990-1993)]

Зимой дошло до этого сена ― и молоко пахнет! **Веришь, нет?**  [Анатолий Трушкин. 208 избранных страниц (1990-2002)]

Comment: Спасибо. То есть, как я понимаю, всё равно нужно ставить вопросительный знак в конце предложения, не обращая внимания, каким является основное предложение. Правильно? Даже с учётом того, что это паразитическое выражение? Каждый из приведённых примеров относится к сознательному употреблению выражения. А как насчёт "бессознательного"? Меня волнует именно то, что употребление этого выражения у героя постоянно встречается в речи. И все эти его "речи" будут иметь на конце вопросительный знак, хотя ни одно из предложений не является вопросительным. Боюсь, читаться будет тяжеловато.