# Хотите (?) верьте (?) хотите (?) нет

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Как расставить знаки?

`Хотите (?) верьте (?) хотите (?) нет (?) наша кошка может открывать двери даже с ручкой шарообразной формы.`

`Веришь (?) нет (?) этот самолëт приземлился через 37 лет после взлëта.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

(1) ***Хотите верьте, хотите нет**: наша кошка может открывать двери / даже с ручкой шарообразной фОрмы.*

**[Устойчивое сочетание](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/2919/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5),** двоеточие при пояснении (интонационное предупреждение).

(2) ***Веришь, нет** — этот самолëт приземлился через 37 лет после взлëта.* Присоединительная интонация.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

[Обсуждение "веришь нет"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/438134/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

[А, веришь, нет, но я всё ещё жду тебя...](https://fanfics.me/read.php?id=48539&chapter=0)